# max_allowed_packet in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried all three method explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)  to `max_allowed_packet`. But no one changes its value in my MySQL 5.6.

I use `show variables like '%max_allowed_packet%'` to see its current value. But it always is `12582912`.

Only changing its value in my.ini is effective.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two values of `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL :

- one on the client side : `[mysql]` section, `[mysqldump]`, `[client]` and more.
- one on the server side : `[mysqld]` section.

The value of `max_allowed_packet` you see with the command `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';` is the one on the **server side**.

In order to increase this value, you must increase both sides : in your server configuration file (`[mysqld]` section in your my.ini file) and in your client configuration file (whether your `[client]` or `[mysql]` section in your my.ini file).

This setting can be changed on the server side without restarting the server if you have the `SUPER` privilege with this command : `mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = numeric;`.

Don't forget to change the '*numeric*' value by a numeric value. Don't forget to change your configuration file too otherwise this value will be reset at reboot.

Comment: which the best value of numeric , my database .sql size is 60MB

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was

1. Start MySQL Workbench 5.6 (tested up to version 6.3)
2. In the navigator go to Instance options file. If the file cannot be found, then create it yourself at `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
# /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
```

3. Click on the *Networking* tab
4. Enter 16M (or any size you wish to have) in the `max_allowed_packet` edit box, click apply and
   restart mysql
5. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` will now give 16777216.

### Alternative

You can set the `max_allowed_packet` directly on the `my.cnf` file as follow:

```
# /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

Answer (score 6):

[MAX ALLOWED PACKET DOCUMENTATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

This value indicates maximum size of one packet, The packet message buffer is initialized to net_buffer_length bytes, but can grow up to max_allowed_packet bytes when needed. This value by default is small, to catch large (possibly incorrect) packets.
You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use.

This server variable can be set globally by running a query.

However, if you do not change it in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file, the value will reset when the server restarts, even if you set it globally.

To change the setting for everyone until the server restarts:

> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;